# How to add new action handler from another class in NetBeans?

Tags: java, events, netbeans, ide, action

I wanted to edit guarded blocks manually but I'm not able to do this so I go to right lower corner in NetBeans where "Events" tab in "properties" is located. And there's a line "actonPerformed", where I can add new handlers. I have internal class ActionHandler:

```
public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source==one) 
        {
            jTextField1.setText(one.getText());
        }                             
    }
}
```

and I want to add something like ActionHandler.class.actionPerformed(evt) to my JButton "one":

```
one.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        oneActionPerformed(evt);
        CalculatorGUI.this.actionPerformed(evt);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that your code is oddly indented and missing a bracket or two, I think.

Comment: @newbiedoodle brackets are ok, IDE shows no error. In second block instead of oneActionPerformed(evt);           CalculatorGUI.this.actionPerformed(evt);   I want to have actionPerformed from ActionHandler class.

Comment: You mean like `one.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());`?

Comment: No, I meant that in the code sample you showed, the top one, you need a third closing bracket. You never end the method. It's not causing the bug in your program, though; I just thought I'd point it out for the sake of clarity and if anyone else thinks that's the issue.

Comment: @newbiedoodle yeah, you are right, I see it now. I copied my code with one missing bracket.

Comment: @Bubletan hmm.. this might work. But how can I add this into guarded block?

Comment: You want it to be inside the anonymous `ActionListener`? Declare an instance `ActionListener handler = new ActionHandler();` and call `handler.actionPerformed(evt);`.

Comment: @Bubletan but the issue is that I want to have it like this: one.addActionListener(handler) but I can't edit guarded blocks created by netbeans. How to bypass it? Or how to edit code in guarded block?